# Install 32 bit glibc on 64 bit CentOS 6

Tags: rpm, centos6, glibc

(a) I was trying to run a Software (64-bit) on a 64 bit Cent OS-6 based System (with no internet access), and I got following error:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

(b) On searching it was understood that 32-bit glibc is to be installed. Searched all dependencies in a different system with internet connection, downloaded from internet, and loaded all rpms in the system via pendrive and tried to install glibc for 32 bit. I got below error message is obtained (when using rpm command):

```
file /usr/bin/ldd from install of glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
file /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl from install of glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
file /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/BIG5-HKSCS.gz from install of glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
file /usr/share/i18n/locales/ca_ES from install of glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
file /usr/share/i18n/locales/or_IN from install of glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: If you used like # `rpm -ivh` to install the package :  `rpm -ivh` is the command for keeping the current version / having two versions of the same package. **Please use yum** : `cd Downloads/ && yum install glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.i686.rpm` ... By the way : Yum is always using the command `rpm -Uvh` for any package install.

Comment: Actually, i want both glibc s to reside.... one 32 bit and one 64 bit.... how to retail both, like in debian we can install both 32 and 64 bit i guess... multiarch support is there. Its possible in windows os also. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

`glibc-common.x86_64` is required for a 64bits CentOS6. When installed, you can install glibc.i686 . Or you can install both with yum :

```
# cd [Downloads]/ && yum install glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686.rpm
```

But I guess you already have glibc-common.x86_64 ?

The unusual issue here is, that you have no glibc.i686 . It's usually installed at OS install as default.

Comment: Both glibc & glibc common x86_64 was present. But 32 bit glib c was not there by default.Finally enabled internet temporarily and configured all repositories,including rpmforge.Then using yum installed all packages... in between yum clean metadata was also helpful, to clear checksum mismatch or related issues. Anyways finally software was up and running... openmotif22, glib2 libxt were other packages required by the software for which internet was a necessity to install neatly using yum , without worrying abt dependencies or conflicts with 64 bit libraries!! Thanks a lot for your replies .