# Failed dependencies when installing MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I tried to install MarkLogic on a CentOS 7.3.1611.

When running

```
rpm -i MarkLogic-9.0-1.1.x86_64.rpm
```

i receive the following message :

```
lsb-core-amd64 is needed by MarkLogic-9.0-1.1.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14) is needed by MarkLogic-9.0-1.1.x86_64
```

I did not find those libraries. Can someone, please, help me install MarkLogic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Frédéric, your best option would be to install using yum by running the following:

> yum install -y MarkLogic-9.0-1.1.x86_64.rpm

This will automatically go through the dependencies and install those as well for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [install guide mentions a number of libraries](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/intro#id_63469) that need to be installed upfront (pay attention to the footnotes). glibc is one of them. As mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703744/918496) you can install those dependencies using yum. That answer talks about RedHat/CentOS 6, but it works for 7 too:

```
yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64 cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-lib cyrus-sasl-md5
```

See also: https://github.com/grtjn/mlvagrant/blob/master/opt/vagrant/install-ml-centos.sh#L17

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Both the 64 bit and 32 bit versions of glibc need to be installed.  I think this may also be the case for some of the 8.0-5.x & 8.0-6.x versions (or at least that's the other times I have seen this behavior).

This related question should point you in the right direction for installing the libraries.

[Install 32 bit glibc on 64 bit CentOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217355/install-32-bit-glibc-on-64-bit-centos-6)